# How to create Paytm CheckSum in dot net Core 2.0?

Tags: .net-core, paytm

I am using dot net Core framework using c# language for my application. How I will be able to generate Paytm CheckSum in my application? As there is no support available for .net core - [Paytm Github](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments)